# Can NetworkManager be used on a server?

Tags: server, configuration, network-manager, networking

On a desktop machine, there's a GUI component to control the connections. But on a server, usually no user is present.

- How do I need to configure NetworkManager to work on a server?
- Where are the keys for WLAN stored/configured?
- How do I tell NetworkManager to bring up a connection or take it down again?

Comment: Are you saying you want a GUI, or is the command line version acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line interface for NetworkManager is `nmcli` command.
You can bring up or down connections with `nmcli`, or use `ifup` and `ifdown` commands bring up or down entire interfaces.